# Which web part is this?

Tags: 2010, web-part

When i create a blog site from the blog site template, it automatically adds this web part called "Archives". Now i would like to know how to add archives, and i would like to know the name of this web part, however when i edit the webpart it does not show the name! Below is an image to demonstrate my problem.

[Image http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/5237/errorjc.png](http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/5237/errorjc.png)

So my question: Which web part is this?

Subquestion: How do i add archives to this web part?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you like to add categories under Archives, like every month would list the categories based on the posts??

Comment: @Vamsi, sorry i mixed up the words, i meant archives, i added it to the main post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Web Part called BlogMonthQuickLaunch. It has no properties and is all generated from the posts list.

If you need to change this one, you must roll your own Web Part. Tip: BlogMonthQuickLaunch is not sealed

Answer (score 1):

You've highlighted the Archives web part, not the Categories web part.  To add new categories, click the "Add New Category" link right above the Archives list you've highlighted.

FYI: Categories is just a list...http://blog/lists/categories.

Comment: Sorry i meant the archives web part ofcourse, i will edit this in the main post.